How to get screen splash animated in application created by PyInstaller
I created PyQt application and bundle it using PyInstaller
Because the unpacking time is huge I need splash screen until all application is uploaded
My top-level program main.py includes
import os,sys
if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    import pyi_splash
.....codes.....
if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    pyi_splash.close()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win=Window()
win.show()

The code to create a bundle is the following:
(actpyenv) PS C:\Alexey\Phyton\PyQt\SoftV2> pyinstaller --onedir –name AppSoft --windowed --icon=images/w.ico --add-data="*.png;." --add-data="*.txt;."  --splash=ZZ5H.gif Main.py

I use ZZ5H.gif animated file is just a moving clock
But unfortunately, I have 2 problems:

The splash image does appear before the whole application but not animated at all

the win instance is the first window. It appears after the splash screen but folded down


If anybody knows how to make the splash screen animated and get the following window on the screen up and not folded
Thank a lot
I just don't know how to move forward please help me!

The pyinstaller splash feature does not support animation (yet, see the still opened feature request). What do you mean by "folded down"? If you mean that it's not focused (and/or is sent back under other windows), then see this.
